# Batch Request in Google calendar Version 3

Tags: asp.net, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing Google Calendar Integration Version 3 for ASP.NET. I got struck on adding/deleting multiple events (Batch Process) together, like in version 2 we had Batch process, but i didn't see the batch process documentation in Version 3 for ASP.NET. So if any one knows about this, please help me...

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Google API Client does not yet support batch requests. You can [star this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=60) to show you are interested in seeing batch requests added to the library.